# Set Unix timestamp value to datetime field

Tags: apex, datetime

I want to set Unix timestamp value to datetime field.

```
string unixDatetime = '1510654220787';
system.debug('!!!unixDatetime='+datetime.newinstance(long.valueOf(unixDateTime)));

string s = string.valueOfGmt(datetime.newinstance(long.valueOf(unixDateTime)));
system.debug('!!!s='+s); 

DateTime dtConverted = DateTime.valueOf((datetime.newinstance(long.valueOf(unixDateTime)).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')));

system.debug('!!!dtConverted='+dtConverted);
```

[image]

```
Account acc = [Select Id,Fully_Paid_Date__c From Account where id ='00127F000006TNUb'];

acc.Fully_Paid_Date__c=dtConverted;
update acc;
```

updated record value

**Fully Paid Date   14/11/2017 9:10 PM**

When I save this value to account object. The time value is stored as less than one hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording of your issue isn't very clear, but here's what I'm seeing:

- The timestamp you're using corresponds to 2017-11-14 10:10:20
- When you save this time to your `Account`, it shows either 2017-11-14 21:10:20 or 2017-11-14 09:10:20 (depending on if you really meant that the time being displayed is 9:10 PM)
- You want the *displayed* time on your `Account` to be 2017-11-14 10:10:20

Looking at [the documentation for Datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm?search_text=datetime), specifically, the description of `Datetime.newInstance(milliseconds)`...

> **newInstance(milliseconds)**
>
> Constructs a Datetime and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public static Datetime newInstance(Long milliseconds)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *milliseconds*
>   Type: Long
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: Datetime
>
> The returned date is in the GMT time zone.

The very last line there is important. When you use `Datetime.newInstance(<timestamp>)`, the result is the time in the GMT/UTC zone.

Datetimes in Salesforce are *always* stored as a timestamp in the GMT/UTC time zone. Salesforce uses the locale set in your user profile (or the org's default locale) to automatically adjust the *displayed* datetime to match your local time zone. Salesforce automatically does the translation in most other cases as well.

Knowing that, you're either in a UTC+1 or UTC+13 time zone. In either case, if you want your `Account` to display the GMT/UTC timestamp as if it were your own local time, you'll need to adjust the `Datetime` to your local time.

Luckily, that's fairly easy to accomplish.

```
Long timestamp = Long.valueOf('1510654220787');

DateTime gmtDatetime = DateTime.newInstance(timestamp);

System.TimeZone myTz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();

Integer millisecondOffsetGmt = myTz.getOffset(gmtDateTime);

DateTime localDatetime = DateTime.newInstance(timeStamp - millisecondOffsetGmt);

system.debug(gmtDatetime);    // This displays (in the debug log) 2017-11-14 10:10:20, regardless of local time
system.debug(localDatetime);  // For me, being UTC-6, this displays 2017-11-14 16:10:20 (again, in the debug log)
```

As for why we need to subtract the offset...
That's because Salesforce *adds* your timezone offset to the GMT/UTC time when displaying it.

Displayed_Time = GMT_Time + Time_Zone_Offset

Since Salesforce assumes (internally) that `DateTime.newInstance(milliseconds)` returns GMT/UTC (and therefore doesn't need automatic adjustment), we need to pass that method the GMT/UTC timestamp that will result in our target datetime being displayed (and therefore automatically adjusted to local time)

GMT_Time = Displayed_Time - Time_Zone_Offset

Comment: what if the timestamp is 1.56514355E9. Then long data type wont support this.How can this be considered?

Comment: @user10727 `newsinstance()` takes a long. Being 64 bits, that's good up to 9.223372e+18, ((2^63) -1, last bit reserved for sign) beyond that, Salesforce doesn't currently provide us any tools. Seeing as how that'll handle things out to about the year 3,000,000 I don't think that's much of a concern for us. If you still have concerns, you should create a new question.